# OSGi Declarative Service - obtain ServiceReference in bind method

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bind, service-reference, declarative-services

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 with Eclipse Gemini JPA / DBAccess. I implemented a declarative ServiceComponent which references EntityManagerBuilderFactory. The bind method looks like this:

```
public void bindEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfBuilder) {
    emfFactoryBuilders.add(emfBuilder);
}
```

However I need the ServiceReference to obtain the properties of this service, like:

```
    ServiceReference ref = ...
    String unitName = (String)ref.getProperty(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.JPA_UNIT_NAME);
```

Do I have to search the ServiceRegistry for this ServiceReference, or is there a more elegant approach?

cheers,
Muki

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Declarative Services 1.1 (the most recent spec version), you can change the signature of your bind method to:

```
public void bindEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder emfBuilder, Map properties)
```

The map will contain the service properties of the bound service.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to have access to ServiceReference object you can use this way (it's supported by 1.0 and 1.1 DS):

```
public void bindEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(ServiceReference reference)
```